# How do I pass list of url's into a variable value in Azure pipelines

Tags: bash, parameters, azure-devops, google-api

My requirement is to have list of url's passed as parameters stored as a variable and pass this variable into (Google pagespeed)API url- one by one to get the API results.

ex - https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=**$(variable from parameter)**&key=xyz

Am passing a list of url's (Space Separated) as parameter values in azure pipelines, How do I store these url's into a variable ?[passing url's as parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhZWa.png)

Am not familiar with regex, tried below setup browsing few blogs to validate url and store them into a variable. I keep on getting syntax error.

```
    regex=""(http|https)://)" 
    + “[a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#?&//=]{2,256}\\.[a-z]” 
    + "{2,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#?&//=]*)""
    echo ${{ parameters.pathsCsv }}
    echo $(Build.BuildNumber)
    
      if [[ ${{ parameters.pathsCsv }} =~ $regex ]]
            then
              appName="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" # Get the sitename from the domain
              echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=appName]$appName"
              
            else
              echo "${{ parameters.pathsCsv }} doesn't match expected URL pattern"
              exit 0
            fi
    
    echo "$(appName)"
```

Comment: Glad to know you found the solution. Please mark your answer so that other people with the same question can find the solution more easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was able to store urls into a variable and print them using below setup

steps:

```
 - task: Bash@3
   inputs:
     targetType: 'inline'
     script: |
       IFS=' ' read -r -a url <<< "${{ parameters.pathUrls }}"
       #echo "${url[0]}"
       for pathUrls in "${url[@]}"
       do
           echo "$pathUrls"
       done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use object type of parameters and loop through parameters. For example:

```
parameters:
- name: Urls
  type: object
  values:
    - value

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- ${{ each parameter in parameters.Urls }}:
  - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=appName]${{ parameter }}"
  - script: echo $(appName)
```

The [script keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#script) is a shortcut for the command-line task. The task runs a script using cmd.exe on Windows and Bash on other platforms.
[image]
You can provide parameter like this when running the pipeline:

[image]

Here is the document about [Loop through parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#loop-through-parameters).

Comment: I want to store the space separated url's which am providing as parameters into a variable value and just print them. I don't have default url's list, they change everytime. Is that possible ?

Comment: @saikumarreddy Please see my updates in the answer. You need to manually convert the url list into the correct format. Does it meet your needs?

Comment: @Wakter Qian-MSFT this answer meets my need. but this is giving me syntax error steps:
- ${{ each parameter in parameters.Urls }}:

Comment: @saikumarreddy Glad to know it helps. Just ignore the warning if the pipeline runs successfully. Appreciate for marking it as an answer which will also help others in the community.

Comment: Am unable to run the pipeline due to this syntax error here steps: - ${{ each parameter in parameters.Urls }}:, Can we have these steps in a bash task ?

Comment: @saikumarreddy I add a screenshot in the answer. It worked on my side. Please pay attention to the space.